# All anagrams in a File

Tags: algorithm, anagram

***Source : Microsoft Interview Question***

We are given a File containing words.We need to determine all the Anagrams Present in it .

Can someone suggest most optimal algorithm to do this.

Only way i know is 
**Sorting all the words,then checking .**

Comment: How are they measuring "optimal"?  Quickest to implement?  Fastest to run?  Least memory used?  Most accurate in counting anagrams?

Comment: Time complexity is the parameter .

Comment: It seems that you already know best method: to sort all letters in each word alphabetically, then compare words with each other (by means of sort or hash).

Comment: Is there a better method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781106/generate-same-unique-hash-code-for-all-anagrams/18785523#18785523

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would be good to know more about data before suggesting an algorithm, but lets just assume that the words are in English in the single case.

Lets assign each letter a prime number from 2 to 101. For each word we can count it's "anagram number" by multiplying its letter corresponding numbers.

Lets declare a dictionary of {number, list} pairs. And one list to collect resulting anagrams into.

Then we can collect anagrams in two steps: simply traverse through the file and put each word to a dictionary's list according to its "anagram number"; traverce the map and for every pairs list with length more then 1 store it's contents in a single big anagram list.

UPDATE:

```
import operator

words = ["thore", "ganamar", "notanagram", "anagram", "other"]

letter_code = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5, 'd':7, 'e':11, 'f':13, 'g':17, 'h':19, 'i':23, 'j':29, 'k':31, 'l':37, 'm':41, 'n':43, 
            'o':47, 'p':53, 'q':59, 'r':61, 's':67, 't':71, 'u':73, 'v':79, 'w':83, 'x':89, 'y':97, 'z':101}

def evaluate(word):
    return reduce( operator.mul, [letter_code[letter] for letter in word] )

anagram_map = {}
anagram_list = []
for word in words:
    anagram_number = evaluate(word)
    if anagram_number in anagram_map:
        anagram_map[ anagram_number ] += [word]
    else:
        anagram_map[ anagram_number ] = [word]

    if len(anagram_map[ anagram_number ]) == 2:
        anagram_list += anagram_map[ anagram_number ] 
    elif len(anagram_map[ anagram_number ]) > 2:
        anagram_list += [ word ]

print anagram_list
```

Of course the implementation can be optimized further. For instance, you don't really need a map of anagrams, just a counters would do fine. But I guess the code illustrates the idea best as it is.

Comment: I am not sure i follow this. Can you please post an example implementation in a UPDATE .

Comment: I follow it now.Now 1 important thing i am unsure is its correctness.Cant the product of two diffrent set of numbers be same ?

Comment: This answer is exceptional .Awesome .

Comment: @akalenuk How do you handle overflow?

Comment: Amazing, I was thinking about a good hash function for similar problems.

Comment: Wonderful. I always mesmerise when I see magical uses of prime numbers. :D

Comment: Genius!. I was always thinking for O(N) time and O(1) space solution. 
1 drawback I see for this solution is overflow issues for large strings and large alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Tries".A trie (derived from retrieval) is a multi way search tree. Tries use pattern matching algorithms. It's basic use is to create spell check programs, but I think it can help your case.. 
Have a look at this link http://ww0.java4.datastructures.net/handouts/Tries.pdf

Comment: Nope, it won't. The question is designed in a way to throw people off track and start thinking about Tries. Tries help for exact matches not for anagrams.

Comment: can use tries, but it'll not make any difference from using hashmap, still needed to sort each word and fill it into the trie or hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this one not to long ago, in a different way.

1. split the file content into an array of words
2. create a HashMap that maps a key string to a linked list of strings
3. for each word in the array, sort the letters in the word and use that as the key to a linked list of anagrams

public static void allAnagrams2(String s) {
        String[] input = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z^\s]", "").split("\s");
        HashMap> hm = new HashMap>();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        String current = input[i];

        char[] chars = current.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        String key = new String(chars);

        LinkedList<String> ll = hm.containsKey(key) ? hm.get(key) : new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.add(current);

        if (!hm.containsKey(key))
            hm.put(key, ll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time complexity is much more compared to akalenuk's answer. Because it involved sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach from the one above. Returning a Hashmap of anagrams instead.

```
Public static Hashmap<String> anagrams(String [] list){

    Hashmap<String, String> hm = new Hashmap<String, String>();
    Hashmap<String> anagrams = new Hashmap<String>();

    for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        char[] chars = list[i].toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        String k = chars.toString();
        if(hm.containsKey(k)){
            anagrams.put(k);
            anagrams.put(hm.get(k));
        }else{
            hm.put(k, list[i]); 
        }
    }
}
```