# Big-O of One Word Anagram

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o, binary-search

I've created a program that takes a string, such as "computer", and outputs all dictionary words that can be formed from it. However I'm having trouble trying to figure out what the program's Big-O efficiency is, as it uses recursion and binarySearch.

Also, can the program be made more efficient? I haven't studied hashmaps or other data structures yet.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class WordScramble {

    static String[] dictArr;
    static int index;

    // print permutation / combination of the characters of the string s (in order)
    public static void permWord(String s) { permWord("", s); }

    private static void permWord(String prefix, String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        if (n != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
               permWord(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, n));
        }
        index = Arrays.binarySearch(dictArr, prefix);
        if (index > 0)
            System.out.println(prefix);
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> getLines(File f) throws FileNotFoundException { 
        ArrayList<String> dict = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            dict.add(scan.next());
        }
        scan.close();
        return dict;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File("wordlist.txt");
        ArrayList<String> dictionary = getLines(f);
        dictArr = new String[dictionary.size()];
        dictArr = dictionary.toArray(dictArr);
        permWord("computer");       
    }
}
```

Comment: Just think about the logic rather than the implementation. How many permutations of a string of length `n` are there? For each one of those there is a binary search. The answer is `n!` - so the complexity is `n!ln(k)` where `n` is the length of the word and `k` is the size of the dictionary. Really any multiple of `n!` is vanishingly small so the big problem here is the size of `n` rather than the size of the dictionary.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That can probably be an answer...

Comment: This question may do better on codereview.stackexchange.com, especially the part where you ask if it could be made more efficient.

Comment: Thank you Boris for understanding the complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to scan the dictionary and check which words are anagrams of the original word.

You can do this check by matching the count of each letter in the original word.

Complexity O(k) where k is the total number of letters in all the words in the dictionary.

This link shows more ways to approach such a problem. [Best algorithm to find anagram of word from dictonary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680145/best-algorithm-to-find-anagram-of-word-from-dictonary/20680234#20680234)

Comment: I like this. My original approach fails when the size of the input word is greater than 9, the number of searches is 9! or 362880, which is double the size of my wordlist, and it only gets exponentially worse for even longer words.