# Creating an anagram dictionary

Tags: java, hashtable

I have to create an anagram dictionary using a hashtable. I take in a word from the user and have to output all the anagrams from that word from my anagram dictionary.

This is my current program, I'm creating a hash function which calculates a hash for each word, and words that are anagrams of eachother will have the same hash and be put in the same slot in the hashtable.

The part I'm having difficulty on is that when I create this map and perform my hashfunction on a user inputted word to get the index of the hashtable, how would I be able to return all the values that were at that index? 
This is my code so far

```
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : " + fis.available());

String content = new String();

while ((content = br.readLine()) != null) {
    singleAddress.add(content);
}

for(int i = 0; i<singleAddress.size(); i++)
{
    char[] chars = singleAddress.get(i).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    int hash = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<chars.length; j++)
    {
        hash = 2*hash + (int)chars[j];
    }
    numbers.put(singleAddress.get(i), hash);
    System.out.println(hash + "  " + i);
}
```

This I believe will create the anagram dictionary in the hashtable but I'm not sure how I would return all the values at a given index.

Comment: There is no way to get out of a `HashMap` a set of all values whose keys collide with a given key. The idea of _collision_, while well-known, is an internal implementation detail. OTOH, if you want to write _your own_ version of `HashMap`, well, that's another matter. You can do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `Map<String, List<String>` (or better a Google Guava `Multimap<String, String>`) and then apply your logic:

- make a lower case version of your word
- sort the characters for the lower case version to for a key
- use that key to put the word into the map

When the user provides input you repeat steps 1 and 2 but use `get(key)` in step 3 and voilà you have your list of anagrams.

Example:

Word = Anna -> key = aann

User input = nana -> key = aann

Then you do `dictionary.get("aann")` and should get the list containing the element "Anna".

*Edit*: Issues with your code

- You don't show the declaration of `singleAddress` and `numbers` but I assume it's a `Set<String>` and a `Map<String, Integer>`.
- In `numbers` the key is the word and the value is the hash. You'd have to iterate over all entries in that map then in order to retrieve all with the same hash. Better swap it around.
- The hash function *might* result in collisions, i.e. the same hash value for non-anagrams (as an example take "ac" and "ba", the hash for "ac" would be `2 * 64 + 66 = 194` and for "ba" it would be `2 * 65 + 64 = 194`). That's why hash sets and maps in Java always use ´hashCode()`_and_`equals()`.`hashCode()`is used to get the bucket which is a list in the map while`equals()` is then used to check whether the keys are actually the same.

Comment: I have to use a hashtable/hashmap unfortunately as it is one of the specs of the assignment. Yes you are right about singleAddress and numbers.
So I want the hash to be the key and the word to be the value? Therefore I'd have to change hash into a string and the word into an int correct?

Comment: @MVantastic `HashMap<String, List<String>>` _is_ a `Map<String, List<String>>` :)

Comment: @MVantastic As for your questions: no, you could just swap the types, e.g. `Map<Integer, String>` etc. The problem still is your hash function. As I said I'd just use a normalized version of the string (i.e. lower case and characters sorted) as the key - see my example.

Comment: I see, so if I use the map<String, List<String>> method, my key would be the world in sorted order and I would make a new list if the key has not been entered before like this?

                map.put(temp, new LinkedList<String>());
and if the key is there, I would simply add the word onto the list?

Comment: @MVantastic exactly - btw, Guava's `Multimap` provides just that, just in case there's any chance for you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a

```
Map<String, Collection<String>>
```

whose KEY would be "sorted String" for a particular word and its value would be a collection of all words  the that can be made with key that are their in your dictionary

For e.g.
    Key: EILNST
    Value: [ELINTS, ENLIST, INLETS, LISTEN, SILENT, TINSEL]

So, in-case you want to search for word "Listen", sort the word and you will get all the anagrams for it and you have to exclude the word form the List retrieved.

Refer to solution: 
[Best algorithm to find anagram of word from dictonary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680145/best-algorithm-to-find-anagram-of-word-from-dictonary)