# Unique hash for same set of characters given in any order?

Tags: java, string, hash, anagram

Consider this example of finding anagrams

```
aabc
abca
```

They both are anagrams, I am looking for a way so that their hash generated by characters is same and unique.

The uniqueness is important so that no two different string `aabc` and `xyaq` generate the same hash

I have no idea about this, but throwing up here to learn what I need to look up for

Comment: What you're seeking is a perfect hash function (assuming that `"aabc".equals("abca")` in a finite `Set` and together represent a distinct element in the `Set`.). Your problem definition needs to be finite for anyone to propose a solution.

Comment: Hashes are essentially never going to be _unique._  Either work out a way that that is acceptable, or find some non-hashing approach.

Comment: [this is an idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18798966/4316015)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the characters in the string and use that as the hash. Strings will have the same hash **if** they are anagrams of each other:

```
String anagramHash(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

This probably won't work if you have code points which aren't on the BMP (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Alternatively, generate a histogram and use that as the hash.

Comment: Different strings can have the same hash, so the *if and only if* part does not hold.